# How can I test integration between apps on mobile?

Tags: android, robotium

I am using Robotium to do the UI tests on my app, but I would like to test the integration between this app and other apps that we developed. I found about UIAutomator, but I would like to know if there is another solution to test this integration using Robotium or another framework. I don't want to mock the apps.